# Industrial Standard for Designing Reporting App Server Layout?

Tags: architecture, report

Given this scenario, currently, (1) I have an application that sends parameters report app then report app queries DB for results and return values back and it generates report and return back to the main application.

I was challenged with another person's opinion, (2) a BETTER design would be, having the application communicating to DB, get ALL of the data required for the report and send to the report app to generate. Reason for this would be the system would be less coupled by the report app, allowing the switching of report app to other reporting apps (e.g. Crystal Report, Jasper) as and when needed. My understanding if this required a lot more effort, such as creating more classes to parameterize objects or stored data into a file such as XML. And this puts a huge load to application.

I would like some opinion on which of the following design would be better or so called commonly practice in the industry?

Thanks

*Sorry, not sure if this question should be under "server fault"

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a reporting app, it's a report rendering app.  The report is still being built in the application, it just isn't rendered yet.

This is possible, but as you said, very expensive.  Also, the requirements for those different reporting frameworks are very different, so you will be doing some serious redevelopment for each reporting framework.

A lot of this depends on the complexity of your data model as compared to the complexity of your domain model.  If your data model (I assume a relational database) is fairly close to your business domain model, then you are almost definitely wasting your time building a decoupled reporting engine.  If you have a large amount of transformative domain models that need to be reported, reproducing that complexity in a reporting system might be cost-prohibitive, and justify using your domain model --> xml representation --> reporting system.

TLDR;  It depends on your requirements... And there isn't enough information here to make a solid recommendation.  In general though, yes, it will be much more expensive.  If it is *just* to remain independent from your reporting framework, it's probably a waste of time.